# how to get object's [[DefaultValue]]

Tags: javascript, ecma262

according to ecma262-3   8.6.2.6 [DefaultValue]
http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-8.6.2.6
**now i want to get the [[DefaultValue]] of [ ]**
so according to ecma,like this:
When the [[DefaultValue]] method of O is called with hint Number, the following steps are taken:
*1. Call the [[Get]] method of object O with argument "valueOf".*
**[ ].valeOf() =>  [ ]//itself**
*2. If Result(1) is not an object, go to step 5.*
**[ ] is an object**
*3. Call the [[Call]] method of Result(1), with O as the this value and an empty argument list.*
**Result(1) => [ ],[ ] don't implement [[Call]]**
*4. If Result(3) is a primitive value, return Result(3).*
**so ,no Result(3),or it is still [ ]**
*5. Call the [[Get]] method of object O with argument "toString".*
**[ ].toString => ""**
*6. If Result(5) is not an object, go to step 9.*
**Result(5) => "" is not an object, go to step 9**
*7. Call the [[Call]] method of Result(5), with O as the this value and an empty argument list.

8. If Result(7) is a primitive value, return Result(7).

9. Throw a TypeError exception.*
**error? god!**

Answer (score 1):

`[[DefaultValue]]` called on array object eventually gets to (and calls) array object's `toString` method. That method is essentially an `Array.prototype.toString` which is the same as calling `Array.prototype.join` on an array object (see 15.4.4.2). So `toString` on an empty array object returns empty string (`""`) which **is** a primitive value and is therefore returned from [[DefaultValue]] internal method.

So [[DefaultValue]] of array is an empty string — **if** `Array.prototype.string` is not overwritten/shadowed, **and if** `Array.prototype.valueOf` is not overwritten/shadowed.

```
[]+''; // ""

Array.prototype.toString = function(){return 1};
[]+''; // "1"

Array.prototype.valueOf = function(){return 2};
[]+''; // "2"
```